# Camel http GET call Status code 406

Tags: rest, get, apache-camel, http-status-code-406

I am trying to make a GET call using Camel with Spring Boot. When I use the following code, I get 406 code. But if I try hitting the endpoint using postman I get 200 with response (json). Please help.

```
from(RouteUtils.buildSedaEndpointWithConcurrentConsumers("sedaEndpointin", domain.getThreads()))
                    .routeId("routeiD")
                    .setProperty("workerId").jsonpath("$.worker_id")
                    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
                    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple(String.format("key=%s&barcode=${exchangeProperty.workerId}", apiKey)))
                    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("https://" + endpoint))
                    .setHeader("Authorization", simple(Auth))
                    .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
                    .to("http4://" + Endpoint)
                    .to("sedaEndpoint");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 406 Not Acceptable The resource identified by the request is only
>   capable of generating response entities which have content
>   characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in
>   the request.

It seems that application/json you are sending is not accepting by client server or might be two different projects on the same port. Check that too.

Try this too... **setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))** my guess.
Read more about status code error [Status Code 406](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)